# Kivy how to create dropdownlist within a GridLayout

Tags: kivy

I have 2 files one of the **py** and the other **kv**, well as the title says, I do not know how to add a dropdown.

---> main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

class MyGridLayout(GridLayout):
    pass

class LayoutsApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGridLayout()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    LayoutsApp().run()
```

---> layouts.kv

```
<MyGridLayout>:
    rows: 2
    id: main_win
    Dropdown:
        id: dropdown
        Button:
            id: btn1
            text: 'option 1'
        Button:
            id: btn2
            text: 'option 2'
    BoxLayout:

    BoxLayout:
```

when compiling, it generates error for that part. How is the correct way to make the call for dropdown-list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Question 3

> call the Button id: btn2, how would I do it? - I mean:class
>   MyGridLayout(GridLayout):

## Solution 3

### Python script

- Add import statements: `from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown`; `from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty`
- Implement `class CustomDropDown(DropDown):`
- In class MyGridLayout, declare an ObjectProperty at class level (e.g. `dropdown = ObjectProperty(None)`; implement a method `dropdown_open(self):`; instantiate the class CustomDropDown and assigned it to `self.dropdown`, etc. Please refer to snippets for detail.

### kv file

- Remove self.dismiss()
- Replace dynamic class, `<CustomDropdown@DropDown>:` with class rule, `<CustomDropDown>:`
- Replace `rows: 2` with `rows: 3`
- Replace `Factory.CustomDropdown().open(self)` with `root.dropdown_open(self)`

## Example 3

### main.py - Snippets

```
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


class CustomDropDown(DropDown):
    pass


class MyGridLayout(GridLayout):
    dropdown = ObjectProperty(None)

    def dropdown_open(self, instance):
        self.dropdown = CustomDropDown()
        self.dropdown.open(instance)
        print(self.dropdown.ids.btn2.text)
```

### layouts.kv - Snippets

```
<CustomDropDown>:
    id: dropdown
    on_select:
        app.root.ids.btn.text = '{}'.format(args[1])
...
<MyGridLayout>:
    rows: 3
    id: main_win

    Button:
        id: btn
        text: 'Press'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '48dp'
        on_release:
            root.dropdown_open(self)
```

## Output 3

[image: Printed btn2.text]

## Question 2

> when I added these commands, it does not work: BoxLayout: orientation:
>   'vertical' size_hint: (.9,.9) BoxLayout: orientation: 'vertical'
>   size_hint_y: 0.5

## Note

*You might need to increase the rows from 2 to 3.*

## Example #2

- Added the config for the two BoxLayout
- For illustration, added colour to the canvas for both BoxLayout

### layouts.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.1
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

<CustomDropdown@DropDown>:
    id: dropdown
    on_select:
        app.root.ids.btn.text = '{}'.format(args[1])
        self.dismiss()

    Button:
        id: btn1
        text: 'option 1'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '48dp'
        on_release:
            dropdown.select(btn1.text)

    Button:
        id: btn2
        text: 'option 2'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '48dp'
        on_release:
            dropdown.select(btn2.text)

<MyGridLayout>:
    rows: 2
    id: main_win

    Button:
        id: btn
        text: 'Press'
        on_release: Factory.CustomDropdown().open(self)
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '48dp'

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint: (.9,.9)
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 1, 0, 0, 1    # red
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint_y: 0.5
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 0, 0, 1, 1    # blue
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
```

## Output #2

[image: App Startup]
[image: DropDown List]
[image: DropDown Selected]

## Solution #1

DropDown widget is like Popup widget i.e. they are special widget.

> Popup / DropDown is a special widget. Don’t try to add it as a child to any other
>   widget. If you do, Popup / DropDown will be handled like an ordinary widget and
>   won’t be created hidden in the background.

Therefore, create a dynamic class with inheritance of DropDown widget, and use Factory to instantiate the class.

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout


class MyGridLayout(GridLayout):
    pass


class LayoutsApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGridLayout()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    LayoutsApp().run()
```

### layouts.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.1
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

<CustomDropdown@DropDown>:
    id: dropdown
    on_select:
        app.root.ids.btn.text = '{}'.format(args[1])
        self.dismiss()

    Button:
        id: btn1
        text: 'option 1'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '48dp'
        on_release:
            dropdown.select(btn1.text)

    Button:
        id: btn2
        text: 'option 2'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '48dp'
        on_release:
            dropdown.select(btn2.text)

<MyGridLayout>:
    rows: 2
    id: main_win

    Button:
        id: btn
        text: 'Press'
        on_release: Factory.CustomDropdown().open(self)
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '48dp'

    BoxLayout:

    BoxLayout:
```

## Output

[image: App Startup]
[image: DropDown opened]
[image: DropDown list selected]

Comment: Hello @ikolim, when I added these commands, it does not work:                                   
 `BoxLayout:
           orientation: 'vertical'             size_hint: (.9,.9)                                                                                                       
   BoxLayout: orientation: 'vertical' size_hint_y: 0.5 `

Comment: After added the config for the two BoxLayouts, it still works.

Comment: perfect, I have a question, to call the **Button** `id: btn2`, how would I do it? - I mean:`class MyGridLayout(GridLayout):`

Comment: Please refer to updated post for the solution to your third question.